# GPS location detect slow or unable receive [Here SDK]

Tags: android, gps, here-api

when trying start navigation in some indoor environment, it will unable receive the GPS signal or detect with very slow, but when using other navigation app(Waze/Google Map/Here) the problem does not occur.

And also some indoor place can receive the gps signal without any problem.

below is my code for PositionListener

```
naviManager.addPositionListener(new WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(positionListener));

private NavigationManager.PositionListener positionListener = new NavigationManager.PositionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPositionUpdated(GeoPosition loc) {
        // the position we get in this callback can be used
        // to reposition the map and change orientation.
        loc.getCoordinate();
        loc.getHeading();
        loc.getSpeed();

        // also remaining time and distance can be
        // fetched from navigation manager
        naviManager.getTimeToArrival(true, Route.TrafficPenaltyMode.DISABLED);
        naviManager.getDestinationDistance();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting the positionManager, maybe you have only passed the GPS option and not the GPS_NETWORK option ?

positioningManager.start(PositioningManager.LocationMethod.GPS_NETWORK);

Comment: i have do this also, but it detect very slow